# Power shell Get-Counter : No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core, performance-monitor, windows-administration

I am new to power shell scripting. I am trying performance monitor commands for local machine in windows power shell with run as administrator.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Counter "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 5 -MaxSamples 5
```

But I am getting below error

**Program 'Get-Counter' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1**

Am unable to understand what is that error and why it is showing. ***I tried same command in another laptop, i am able to get response.***

Comment: Get-Counter was first introduced in PS v3.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-3.0)

Make sure you have atleast version 3.0 installed. You can get your PS-Version with `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`.

Comment: My power shell version is 5.1

Comment: repair your windows counters. https://support.uptimesoftware.com/article.php?id=162

Comment: can you get that counter to list as part of the available sets? something like this >>> `(Get-Counter -ListSet 'processor' -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME).Counter` <<<

Comment: also, why do you have this tagged with `powershell-core`? your comment says you are running ps5.1 ...

Comment: Lee, get-Counter itself failing. i tried same command in Windows powershell and also powershell and Windows Powershell ISE all powershell related.

Comment: @Aaron, like you said i am thinking something is broken in my laptop. i tried "lodctr /r" resulted as "Info: Successfully rebuilt performance counter setting from system backup store"

In the link you provided , i did first step but nothing works